# Mount SMB share as different volume

Tags: centos, mount, smb, volume

CentOS 6 server currently has the following volumes:

```
/boot
/
```

Is it possible to create a new volume that is a mounted SMB share? E.g.:

```
/nas
```

Currently this share is mounted by fstab to /mnt/nas, however I'd like to not be under /. I need to backup the entire / volume to this SMB share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way to move a volume from one mount point to another is something like:

1) Create the new mount point:

```
mkdir /nas
```

2) Unmount the SMB share from the old mount point:

```
umount /mnt/nas
```

3) Open /etc/fstab in your favorite text editor and change "/mnt/nas" to "/nas":

```
${EDITOR:-editor} /etc/fstab
```

4) Mount the SMB share at the new mount point:

```
mount /nas
```

5) Remove the old mount point since you don't need it anymore:

```
rmdir /mnt/nas
```

But that probably won't solve your *real* problem since "/nas" is still under "/".

What program are you going to use when you're making the backup?

Some of them have options to either skip a directory (in your case you would want to skip "/mnt/nas" and/or "/nas") or to stay on one filesystem (in your case you would then have to make two backups, one of "/" and one of "/boot").

If possible, I would suggest finding a backup program that lets you stay on one filesystem. You most likely also want to skip "/dev", "/proc", "/run", "/sys" and maybe more. That's a lot of typing and you're likely to forget to skip a (pseudo) filesystem.

It's much easier to specify that you want to backup *this* filesystem and stay on that filesystem, even if it means you'll have to run the backup program first for "/" and then for "/boot".

For "cp", "rsync" and "tar", the option you're looking for is "--one-file-system".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to setup ShadowProtect SPX which does not appear to allow for the skipping of any directory. In fact the / filesystem cannot be selected at all. I think I'll have to try a different product.